# How to use a function returning nvarchar inside IN operator ()

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have written a function in SQL which returns a coma separated quoted values like `('IN0011000','IN0011003','IN0011005','IN0011007')`

The function is

```
FUNCTION LOS_USER_Branch_List(
@UserID NVARCHAR (100)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR (max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @loc_flag NVARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @branch_code NVARCHAR (max)
DECLARE @temp_branch_code NVARCHAR (max)
DECLARE @branch_name NVARCHAR (max)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR (max)
SET @loc_flag=''
SET @branch_code=''
SET @sql=''
  SELECT @loc_flag=loc_flag,@branch_code=RF_BRANCH_CODE,@branch_name=RF_BRANCH_NAME FROM RLOS_MASTER_USERS WHERE USER_ID =@UserID
 
  SET  @branch_code=''''+@branch_code+''''
  IF @loc_flag = 'B'
BEGIN
SET  @branch_code=@branch_code
END
ELSE IF @loc_flag = 'A'
BEGIN
DECLARE @branch_list NVARCHAR (max)
SET @branch_list=''
--SET @branch_name = REPLACE(@branch_name, ',', ''',''');
--SET @branch_name = ''''+@branch_name+''''
DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
   SELECT Org_Unique_ID FROM RLOS_MASTER_ORGANISATION WHERE Org_area IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@branch_name,','))
   OPEN c1
   FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @temp_branch_code
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
     
      SET @branch_code =@branch_code+','+''''+@temp_branch_code+''''
     
      FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @temp_branch_code
    END
    CLOSE c1;
    DEALLOCATE c1;
    END
RETURN @branch_code
END
```

But I am unable to get the result set when I trigger the above function through a query

```
SELECT ORG_REGION AS 'Region' FROM RLOS_MASTER_ORGANISATION WHERE Org_Unique_ID IN (dbo.LOS_USER_Branch_List('xyz'))
```

Comment: `IN` don't takes a comma-separated string. It needs a number of separate parameters.

Comment: that looks more loke sql server than mysql, is this correct tagged?

Comment: yep......thats ms sql ......wrongly tagged

Comment: Because your approach is completely wrong. Your function (if that is, indeed, the appropriate mechanism to use) should return a table, not a scalar value.

Comment: You're looking for an inline tabled valued function... which returns a table... not a scalar function.

Answer (score 1):

If your using sql server 2016 or later you can use `string_split` as like as this:

```
SELECT ORG_REGION AS 'Region' FROM RLOS_MASTER_ORGANISATION WHERE Org_Unique_ID IN (select * from string_split((select dbo.LOS_USER_Branch_List('xyz')),','))
```

**Reference** :[string_split reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

But if you use older version you can create a function to separate your string to table with one column and replace it by `string_split`

For example you can use a function like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SimpleSplitFunction
(
  @List      nvarchar(max),
  @Delimiter nchar(1)
)
RETURNS @t table (Item nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
  SET @List += @Delimiter;
  ;WITH a(f,t) AS  
  (
    SELECT CAST(1 AS bigint), CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t + 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List, t + 1) 
    FROM a WHERE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List, t + 1) > 0
  )  
  INSERT @t SELECT SUBSTRING(@List, f, t - f) FROM a OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
  RETURN;  
END
GO
```

And  change your code to use it like below :

```
SELECT ORG_REGION AS 'Region' FROM RLOS_MASTER_ORGANISATION WHERE Org_Unique_ID IN (select * from dbo.SimpleSplitFunction((select dbo.LOS_USER_Branch_List('xyz')),','))
```

Note : If it possible don't use `CURSOR` in your scripts. If you use this function result as `nvarchar` and always change it to table type so change your function type to table. like below :

```
FUNCTION LOS_USER_Branch_List(
@UserID NVARCHAR (100)
)
RETURNS table
AS
BEGIN
-- your scripts
End
```